# TypeError when using a list of lists

Tags: python, list, append

I am trying to append XY coordinates from a list to another list so I can plot patches around the scatter plot of 15 different objects. But I get an error, `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple` when trying to run the code.

The dataset I'm working on is formatted horizontally. The data is read that results in a list of x-coordinates and a list of y-coordinates.

Dataset example:

```
data = [[],[]]
data[0] = [random.sample(range(80), 10) for _ in range(6)] #x-coordinates
data[1] = [random.sample(range(80), 10) for _ in range(6)] #y-coordinates

x_data = data[0]  
y_data = data[1]
```

I plot a scatter and then want to add circles of different radiuses around that scatter plot. I plot the scatter as such, which works fine:

```
scatter = ax.scatter(x_data[0], y_data[0], zorder = 5, s = 20)
```

Where I get the error is using the following code:

```
#creating list of patches
players = []
for n in range(10):
    ##as there are always 3 circles, append all three patches as a list at once
    players.append([
        mpl.patches.Circle((x_data[0,n],y_data[0,n]), radius = 2, color = 'black', lw = 1, alpha = 0.8, zorder = 4),
        mpl.patches.Circle((x_data[0,n],y_data[0,n]), radius = 4, color = 'gray', lw = 1, alpha = 0.8, zorder = 3),
        mpl.patches.Circle((x_data[0,n],y_data[0,n]), radius = 6, color = 'lightgrey', lw = 1, alpha = 0.8, zorder = 2)
])

##adding patches to axes
for player in players:
    for circle in player:
        ax.add_patch(circle)
```

I get the error for

```
mpl.patches.Circle((x_data[0,n],y_data[0,n]), radius = 2, color = 'black', lw = 1, alpha = 0.8, zorder = 4),

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error speaks for itself. This is because `x_data` is a list. It doesn't support multiple indexing. If you want to do that convert `x_data` to a numpy array. Else you can also do `x_data[0][n]`.

Also, you have a loop running from 0 to 14, but your `x_data` and `y_data` have shapes of `(6,10)`. You might want to check that.